# How to import react app from GitHub as a component to new react app?

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, yarnpkg

**How can I import React app from my GitHub account**, as a component to a new React app?

For example, I built a React app of `NavBar` and uploaded it to a GitHub. And I would like to import this `NavBar` app as a component to the header component at the new React project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install the package using npm in the following way:

```
npm install --save your_repo_url/master
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```sh
npm install git://github.com/username/repo.git#branch-name

yarn add git://github.com/username/repo.git#branch-name

// Example
yarn add git://github.com/denvash/react-pagination-example.git#master
```

Then import it according to the repo path, for example:

```
import Pagination from 'react-pagination/src/components/Pagination.react'
```

Comment: Now I think I need a node module.